# How can we validate json based on key value pair in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, read-write, web-api-testing

I haved worked around with Jmeter for load Testing. But now i am focusing on api automation.

Reading file from CSV for the endpoints and Response expected, only challenge i am facing whether how to validate the json based on key value pair, so that i can validate only those data in which i am interested and not whole JSON body.

In java using eclipse we can do this using below Method:

```
JSONObject obj1=null,obj2=null;

        obj1=new JSONObject(actual);
        obj2=new JSONObject(required);
    Iterator<?> keys = obj2.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() ) {
         String key = (String)keys.next();
        if(obj2.get(key) instanceof JSONArray)
        {
            if(!compareJSONArray(obj2.getString(key),obj1.getString(key)))
            {return false;}
            status=true;
        }else if(obj2.get(key) instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            if(!compareJSON(obj2.getString(key),obj1.getString(key)))
            {return false;}
            status=true;    
        }else{
            if(obj2.getString(key).equalsIgnoreCase(obj1.getString(key)))
                    {

                status=true;
                    }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        }
```

How can i do this following in Jmeter. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) to validate JSON responses using [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) language expressions.

JSON Path Assertion can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter JSON Path Assertion via Plugins Manager]

---

Another option is using [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/). Groovy is almost fully Java-compatible so you should be able to re-use your existing Java code. Alternatively be aware that [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so you can re-implement your JSON comparison logic using Groovy style scripting.

Answer (score 1):

[JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) allow you to execute Java language

You can put your code in JSR223 Sampler and use variables using: `vars.get("VARIABLE_NAME")` or properties: `props.get("propertyName")`

You can effect result using:

> ```
> SampleResult.setSuccessful(true/false)
> SampleResult.setResponseCode("code")
> SampleResult.setResponseMessage("message")
> ```